# JQuery clone table row and increment input box id

Tags: jquery

Trying to copy the previous row (or create blank row) and have it increment each input fields id and name by 1. However all it is doing its tacking the digit onto the end. Resulting in id012345 etc.

I know .slice() can remove the last character but I am failing at implementing it correctly. Any suggestions?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){

var i = 0;

//clone previous row
$(".clone").click(function() {
  $("table tr:last").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
      'id': function(_, id) { return id.slice(0, - 1) + i },
      'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
      'value': function(_, value){ return value }
    });
  }).end().appendTo("table");
  i++;
});

//create blank row
$(".blank").click(function() {
  $("table tr:last").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
      'id': function(_, id) { return id.slice(0, - 1) + i },
      'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
      'value': ''
    });
  }).end().appendTo("table");
  i++;
});


});     
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking this:

```
$("#clone").click(function() {
    $("#cloningTable tr:last").after($("#cloningTable tr:last").clone());
    $("#cloningTable tr:last").attr("id", "tr" + $("#cloningTable tr").length);
});
```

Simply use the `length` of the `tr`s to determine the ID.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/ufN38/

Edit: I am assuming you will want to edit the ID of whatever is inside the table rows as well. Simply modify my code (e.g. `$("#cloningTable tr:last input").attr("id", "input" + $("#cloningTable tr").length);`) to apply the same concept to child elements.